# type object got multiple values for keyword argument 'visible'

Tags: python, matplotlib, subplot

I am getting the error

```
type object got multiple values for keyword argument 'visible'
```

when I am trying to plot some graphs. I am using the code

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
```

I have also tried inserting an argument in the function:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(3)
```

but still it is not working. I am not understanding how to resolve this issue. I have made subplots before but this is the first time I am getting such error.

Comment: can you please post the full code that you are using to base your plot?

Comment: @tylerjames

`import fastf1 as ff1`
`from fastf1 import plotting`
`from matplotlib import pyplot as plt`
`from matplotlib.pyplot import figure`
`import pandas as pd`
`plotting.setup_mpl()`
`fig, axs = plt.subplots(2)`
I think the problem is occuring because of different libraries I am using. I tried the same command for subplots while only importing matplotlib and it worked.

Comment: @tylerjames I found the problem. It is in the line `plotting.setup_mpl()` Before adding this line of code, the subplots are being plotted but as soon as I add the above piece of code, it is showing the error. Also even after removing this line of code and then run the whole code, it shows an error. Feels like this `plotting.setup_mpl()` is changing something internally after being run atleast once